# Integral over solid angle in Cartesian coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have an integral that is an average of some (unknown) function $f$ over solid angle:

$$\bar{f} = \frac{1}{4\pi} \iint\limits_\Omega f \sin\theta~\mathrm{d}\theta~\mathrm{d}\phi$$

I use the physics convention where $\theta$ is the polar angle and $\phi$ is the azimuthal angle.

For computational reasons, it would be useful to recast this as a volume integral in Cartesian coordinates (the exact reasons are somewhat out of the scope of this question).

My hangup is that I essentially want to recast a surface integral as a volume integral. The divergence theorem comes to mind, but I'm not sure how to do the transformation without making any assumptions about $f$.

**My attempt:**

If we write the equation as

$$ \bar{f} = \frac{1}{4\pi} \iint\limits_S f \left(\frac{\hat{r} \cdot \hat{n}}{r^2}\right) \mathrm{d}S $$

for a surface $S$ (a formula I found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle)), we could define $\vec{F} = f \hat{r} / r^2$ and then use the divergence theorem to write as a volume integral. Does this make any assumptions about $f$? What exactly is the surface $S$ in this context?

Comment: But you can't use the Divergence Theorem with that $\vec F$ because this vector field is singular at the origin!! This is where Gauss's Law comes from, after all.

Comment: @TedShifrin If I can't use the divergence theorem, then I'm really stuck. What's the correct approach?

Comment: If you have a $f$ on the unit sphere, then you could just use $\vec F = f\hat r$.The question is how to scale $f$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't have the function $f$ on the surface. Is there another way?

Comment: You need to create a *differentiable* vector field $\vec F$ on the interior of the unit sphere in terms of values only on — say — the unit sphere. The problem is that taking $\vec F = f(x/r)\hat r$ won't give something continuous, let alone differentiable, at the origin. But if you take something like $\vec F = f(x/r)r^k\hat r$ for a suitable exponent $k$, that ought to take care of the singularity at the origin when you differentiate.  (Look up formulas for divergence in spherical coordinates.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Without knowing the analytic form of $f$, I'm afraid I wouldn't know what to choose for an appropriate $k$. I know the divergence of $\hat{r} / r^2$ is nonzero only at the origin, so it is a $\delta$ function. Is there any way to exploit $\delta$ functions for my problem? Or have I already messed up by applying the divergence theorem at all?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious choice for the surface is a sphere of radius $1$. For the sphere $\hat n=\hat r$, so $\hat r\cdot\hat n=1$. Also $r=1$, so $1/r^2=1$ on the surface. Note that you still want to use your expression for $\vec F$.